# Finding the max repeated value in dictionary keys python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary in python as

```
d = {(2,4):40,(1,2,4):8}
```

in this dict keys are tuples,
Values are count of each element in the tuple

I need output 1 more dictionary as
Total count of values in all the tuples

```
out={2:48,4:48,1:8}
```

The example I gave is small dictionary but I have very large dictionary so time complexity plays the key role
Can someone help me out?

Comment: You want to find the ones with biggest counts? Like 4 or 2 becaue they all have 48?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single pass, just iterate over the keys and add the corresponding value. You can use a `collections.Counter` or whatever dict/dict-like container you prefer:

```
>>> origin = {(2,4):40,(1,2,4):8}
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> for k, v in origin.items(): # python 2 use .iteritems()
...     for x in k:
...         counts[x] += v
...
>>> counts
Counter({2: 48, 4: 48, 1: 8})
```

Comment: Hm. You use a `Counter` without utilizing its counting ability. It does nothin g a common `dict` couldn't do (or a `defaultdict(int)`).

Comment: @schwobaseggl of course I use it's counting ability.

Comment: Not in any way any other dict couldn't do.

Comment: @schwobaseggl so? This is the most straight-forward way. It is fast, and memory efficient.

Comment: I don't say it is wrong ;) I just think this is bad example to show someone a `Counter` whose inherent advantage is its performant constructor that one can pass an iterable, but a much better chance to introduce the OP to a `defaultdict`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I entirely disagree. The `Counter` object has other advantages, such as customized `+` and `-` operators for adding `Counter` objects just as you'd wish. In any event, performance is a concern, as per the OP, and your construction is simply going to be slower, unless the values are small (i.e. one or two), but even then you construct and iterate over `range` objects, again, using a generator (which will be slow).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163040/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 1):

One can utilize the capability of multiple [`Counters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to be  handily summed to create some neat one-liners, but their performance can't compete with [juanpa's explicit loop approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221317/finding-the-max-repeated-value-in-dictionary-keys-python/answer-48221400) (timings for the original `dict`):

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

# 1
out = sum((Counter({x: v for x in k}) for k, v in d.items()), Counter())
# timeit: 16.2

# 2
out = reduce(add, (Counter({x: v for x in k}) for k, v in d.items()))
# timeit: 10.8

# 3
# juanpa's approach
# timeit: 3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dict = {(2,4):40,(1,2,4):8}    
Out={}

for k,v in Dict.items():
    for i in k:
        if i in Out:
            Out[i] += v
        else:
            Out[i] = v

print(Out)

{2: 48, 4: 48, 1: 8}
```